# SQL Server 2005 remote connections

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, connection

I've a public IP and I would like to connect to my remote SQL server via Internet.
This computer is connected at router and I've just set Port Forwarding into it.

I've also set my Windows firewall rule.
I've followed this tutorial: http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/

But I can't access to my SQL Server, can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to ping server and connecting to port via telnet. If port closed, try to connect from localhost. If u can to connect from localhost, but can't to do in from other hosts, see MS SQL connection settings, firewall settings, security rules (allow to connect not localhost only).

Comment: If I try within my local network (for example 192.168.0.11:1433) all works correctly.

Comment: Do u can connect to this host from external zone? (ping, http, etc for example)

Comment: I can connect to other ports, as 80 or 8080 for example.

Comment: See firewall settings, and check in connection propertes  here (manual for 2008, should help) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

When you set the ip address allowed, you have to specify Dynamic TCP Port.